# java7 bug with JTextField when reopening JDialog that has been setVisible(false)

Tags: java, swing

I have a strange issue with our application that only manifests itself in java7, everything worked flawlessy in java6.
I have a product-choosing JDialog that has a JTable, an ok button, a cancel button, a jtextfield for searching and a jcheckbox "keep window open".

The idea is, that if "keep window open" is selected, then a press to the ok button will not dispose the jdialog, but instead set a reopen-variable to true, and call setVisible(false).
Then I have the following code to reopen it:

```
while(SelectionDialog.isReopen()){
    Product p1 = SelectionDialog.reopen();
    if (p1 == null) return;
    //Do stuff with product
}
```

In SelectionDialog:

```
public static SelectionDialog reopen = null; //Is instanciated to current jdialog if ok button is pressed and reopen-checkbox is selected. setvisible(false) is then called instead of dispose()

public static Product reopen() {
  SelectionDialog.reopen.setVisible(true);
  return SelectionDialog.returnedData;
}
```

The strange thing is, that when the JDialog is redisplayed, the jtextfield is not focusable/clickable. Everything else seems ok. If I then press the ok button and it reopens, the jtextfield is ok again, but if I press ok another time it is not focusable/clickable again.

The jtextfield displays text, but there is no blinking cursor when it does not work.So every other time the jtextfield simply doesn't work, and every other time it works.

All these methods return true for the jtextfield: isEnabled, isEditable, isDisplayable, isVisible, isFocusable, isOpaque, isShowing, isValid.

Calling updateUI on jtextfield in swingutilities.invokelater before setVisible(true) on jdialog does not solve the problem. Neither does requestfocusinwindow.

The only thing that seems to work to bring the jtextfield back from the dead is switching to another program, and then switching back to my java-program.

I have tested, and the problem persists in both jdk1.7.0_03 and 1.7.0_51.
I don't have this problem in java6 and before.

What can be causing the problem? (I have removed everything from "//Do stuff with product" in case this did something, but the problem persists).

And even if you don't know what causes the problem, does anyone have any suggestions to a workaround that may work?

UPDATE:
Thanx to MadProgrammers comments, it now works with the following code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ReopenProductList()); //Instead of while-loop

private class ReopenProductList implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
    if (SelectionDialog.isReopen()){
      Product p1 = SelectionDialog.reopen();
      if (p1 == null) return;
      //Do stuff with product
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ReopenProductList());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The while loop is scary. Is this done within the context of the EDT?

Comment: Yes, it is done in the Event Dispatch Thread, when the user clicks on an add-product-button on a toolbar.

Comment: You should do nothing in the EDT that may block it. Java 7 tightened this up and has highlighted a lot of bad code

Comment: I didn't think that was true for modal JDialogs, as these block on setVisible(true)? But I can try to move my code to a thread and/or swingutilities.invokelater and see what happens.

Comment: That's a good point, but your description is a classic description of a blocked EDT...

Comment: That did it! :-) using subsequent invokelaters instead of the while-loop solved the issue. I will update the question with the solution code shortly. MadProgrammer please make an answer of your comments so that I can credit you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description of the problem, it would appear that you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread by using the `while loop`.

Having had a situation when testing Java 7 early on (it actually deadlocked on `SwingUtiltiies.invokeLater`). We never found the fault, as we re-wrote the entire action of code (the original was funky), it would suggest that the threading model,has changed between Java 6 & 7.

Try removing the while loop from the EDT